# Is it possible to use data-filter style on simple search field in JQM?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am working on a small mobile project using [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com) and i need to provide search option for users. Default search input is good, but i want something more... I found that when using list you can add `data-filter="true"` and it looks like this

[image]

Is it possible to do with simple input and submit button?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do it. You can take a text box and as user types catch the event and call the web service or relevant data source dynamically and fill the listview below.

Else you can use existing [pre written library such as this one](http://andymatthews.net/read/2012/03/27/jQuery-Mobile-Autocomplete-now-available).

Check out the [example here](http://andymatthews.net/code/autocomplete/).

Comment: Nice answer, need to remember this one +1